# How to connect php application to localdb on sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc, toad

I'll send postcard to any clever quy letting me move forward with the following issues:

It is visible for Toad and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Here is the code:

```
$serverName = "(Local)\\Takdzwiedz_DB";

$db = "eraz_v3_local";

$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "$db");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

sqlsrv_errors() result:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]`enter code here`
```